# Are there any methods that change the rate at which a Stalker/Grustrag 3/ Harvester appears at?

Tags: warframe

Recently, I have been running into no Grustrag Threes, and I have never seen a Harvester.  Are there any ways to increase the rate at which they spawn in besides more people in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, having more people in the game doesn't actually increase your chances.  However, having more **marked** players in your session does help. 1 mark gives your a 2.5% chance of spawn and every person marked after that adds .5%.  Also the Grustrag / harvetser / stalker only spawn between 30-240 seconds so keep your missions short.

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides having the additional people in your squad, it's also important to make sure that they are in the squad from the start. The chances are determined at the mission's start. For this reason, it is best to assemble a squad for hunting, rather than relying on matchmaking.

Having the entire squad be marked is probably a good idea as well, though I'm not sure the exact effect it has, since info provided by DE only gave anything for the actual squad size.